# How to restore deleted Telegram chat?

Tags: restore, chat, telegram-messenger

One of my chat partners has unfortunately cleared our entire (now almost a year long) conversation history in Telegram. It happened to contain really important info. Is it possible to restore it somehow?

What I have tried: I have two copies of Telegram, one on my Android10 phone and one on my Win10 laptop. I have seen the deletion on my phone so this change has already been synched to my phone. But I have not started the desktop app since the deletion so it may contain the last, undeleted state of chats. So I tried starting my desktop Telegram with disabled internet connection but it won't start that way..

Any ideas with this? Or is there a better, maybe even official way to restore a chat?

Comment: Probably not, see [Telegram adds ‘delete everywhere’ nuclear option to private chats — killing chat history | TechCrunch](https://techcrunch.com/2019/03/25/going-going-gone/?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAAIvnMwwBMuv3UtStNdeyIlk5rVBS4kQd2QGhBlwxoLOkMD0TlgN8Jwmjv-kh4fFMjl0SHseMAn2XmnPFESvSUHavB9J2ygGDoxQTUmd1JjRHJ2jl6CWBdRz8MK-c5OjbURXVN9F7iPzefw1Fa2BkG_ggKfUtt1CFtd1Iq5Oh8TaH) for the reasons why.

Comment: __It happened to contain really important info__ This may be the reason he deleted it in the first place.